Movie about 3 witches who have to try not to use their magic in the mortal world. Aired on disney
I remember watching a movie on Disney where 3 (at least I think its 3) witches try to live in the mortal world without using their magic.
If they used their magic, they'd get caught by some evil villain who's after them. This is also why they have to live in hiding. I also remember there being a little kid living with them (a girl i think). They lived in a cute cottage house.
At one point they did cave in and used their magic which the villain eventually caught on and hunted them down so they had to run again.
It wasn't an animated movie so its definitely not sleeping beauty even though it sounds similar.
The movie was aired on Disney, probably around 10 years ago. It also had Hocus Pocus vibe and setting but the story was different. The movie was probably made in the 1990s or maybe even late 1980s. 

Could it possibly be Practical Magic (1998) ?
There were two sister witches, instead of three.

Sisters Sally and Gillian Owens have a special bond with each other
  despite being different in personality and outlook. Having grown up
  with their spinster Aunts Frances and Jet in the long time Owens
  family home on an island off the coast of Massachusetts following the
  death of their father and then their mother, they are the latest in a
  long line of witches. Rumors of the Owens women being witches have
  existed for generations in the small close minded town in which they
  live, despite there being no hard evidence. The Owens women are also 
  under a curse that any man with who they fall in love is doomed. With
  this experience, extroverted Gilly decides to leave the island to live
  life to the fullest, in the process falling for Jimmy Angelov, an
  ethnic Bulgarian who grew up near Transylvannia. More introspective
  Sally, who has sworn off the use of magic except in its most practical
  sense, has taken measures not to fall in love because of the curse,
  but ends up falling for and marrying Michael, a local merchant, the
  two who end up having two daughters of their own. The curse works its
  way into both Gilly and Sally's lives in different ways. The outcomes
  of the curse on their collective lives become more complicated with
  the arrival into town of Tuscon police detective Gary Hallet, whose
  arrival is not by accident and involves more than just his stated
  professional purpose.

The house/cottage:

